# Is there a way to capture js errors but not fail testcafe tests because of them?

Tags: javascript, testing, error-handling, automated-tests, testcafe

I'm currently starting to write some TestCafe tests, and came across an issue in our website whilst running them - a JS error in the console fails the test. Naturally, I was quite pleased that my test had caught this, but it would mean that even if a JS error happens that is low priority and affects no users directly, our tests may fail and prevent a build.

Now this may be a workflow some want, but for us we'd rather raise a ticket and address it in a parallel workflow rather than block everyone because of a JS error. I'm aware of the `--skip-js-errors` option, however this just throws away all the errors entirely. Is there a middle ground, like converting the errors to warnings, or simply adding some sort of after-test function that logs out any JS errors that occurred during the test run? I've tried adding an `afterEach` to my fixture like so:

```
.afterEach(async t => {
  const { error } = await t.getBrowserConsoleMessages();

  console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

But with `--skip-js-errors` this does nothing. I'd love some pointers on this please!

My goal, in case it wasn't clear - I want to *see* the possible JS errors in my TestCafe run so that I can log them and make tickets off them, but I don't want them to fail the test run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TestCafe does not provide such functionality out of the box. As you correctly mentioned, the `--skip-js-errors` flag ignores all errors and does not log them.

However, you can achieve the desired functionality using the Script Injecting mechanism. Please refer to the following article for more details: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/common-concepts/inject-scripts-into-tested-pages.html#inject-script-code

I recommend you continue using the `--skip-js-errors` flag and add a custom `window.onerror` handler. Please see the example:

```
fixture `fixture`
    .page `../pages/index.html`;

test.clientScripts({
    content: `
        window.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
            console.error(e.message); 
        });`
})(`Skip error but log it`, async t => {
    console.log(await t.getBrowserConsoleMessages());
});
```

In this code, I add the `error` event handler. Inside the handler, I call the `console.error` method. In this case, `t.getBrowserConsoleMessages` will return the correct log of errors.

Please use this approach along with the `--skip-js-error` flag.
Thus, the command will be the following: `testcafe chrome test.js --skip-js-errors`.

Comment: Hi Alex - thanks! Is there some way to run this globally on all testcafe tests instead of having to inject it in each file?

Comment: Yes, check this out in the article Alex mentioned.

Comment: @alex-kamaev, Hi Alex ... using the code you provided, I was able to get some of the errors. Is there a way to get "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" from the browser. If i understood the docs correctly, this is not possible with getBrowserConsoleMessages(). Do you know of a way that I can?

Comment: Thank you for creating a separate thread with this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61447018/how-to-capture-server-console-error-wanrings-in-testcafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61447018/how-to-capture-server-console-error-wanrings-in-testcafe)